# как поставить содержимое Bootstrap по центру?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <body class="container-fluid wrapper">


    <div class="row sign ">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1>Choose your language</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row lang1 text-center ">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-centered ">
        <h2 >RUS</h2>
        <div class="block"></div>      
         </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
        <h2>ENG</h2>
         <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
        <h2>GER</h2>
         <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
        <h2>UKR</h2>
         <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      </div>



   <div class="row lang2 text-center ">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>KZ</h2>
         <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>JP</h2>
         <div class="block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>CN</h2>
         <div class="block"></div>
      </div>


      </div>


    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

1. Может в Bootstrap есть класс, который может отцентрировать всё содержимое?
2. Как лучше сделать выбор языков на сайте? Что использовать? JavaScript или jQuery?

Comment: Я думаю что можно сделать иконками стран, тогда каждый поймет где его страна, и текста писать не нужно :)

Comment: Дайте `css` для `.block`

Comment: Отцентрировать как? Все элементы в ряд и по центру? Или вы хотите чтобы у вас второй был таким чтобы занимать равное кол-во пространства между ним? типа `justify-content: space-between` ? Не совсем очевидно что вы хотите

Comment: чтобы не пропсиывать в флекс,а чисто в бутстрапной строке в хтмл просто сделать ?типа есть класс row и рядом с ним написать какой то класс,который все содержимое ставит по центру и по вертикали по центру

Comment: @FaceBook `.justify-content-center` и `.align-items-center`

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не понятен. Да, в бутстрап есть такой класс, и вы его используете. Но пример не доверстан и не воспроизводим относительно вашего скрина, ваши стили не дописаны, бутстраповские не подключены, зачем-то подключены скрипты, хотя они в примере не имеют никакого значения. + есть не закрытый див:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body class="container-fluid wrapper">


  <div class="row sign ">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <h1>Choose your language</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row lang1 text-center ">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered ">
      <h2>RUS</h2>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
      <h2>ENG</h2>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
      <h2>GER</h2>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-centered">
      <h2>UKR</h2>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="row lang2 text-center ">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>KZ</h2>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>JP</h2>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>CN</h2>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>


  </div>


</body>
```